# Distributing boxes in a 12-column grid

Tags: math, grid

Suppose we have a *N* boxes. I'd like to distribute them in a 12-column grid in such a way that each row is filled in any case.

The width of the boxes should be the same as far as possible. The minimum width for each box is 3.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to come up with a solution to compute the widths of each box for a given *N* (except manually).

#### Example for N from 1 to 7

```
| N |  Grid   |
+---+---------+
|   |         |
| 1 |   12    |
|   |         |
| 2 |  6  6   |
|   |         |
| 3 |  4 4 4  |
|   |         |
| 4 | 3 3 3 3 |
|   |         |
| 5 |  6  6   |
|   |  4 4 4  |
|   |         |
| 6 |  4 4 4  |
|   |  4 4 4  |
|   |         |
| 7 |  4 4 4  |
|   | 3 3 3 3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to find partition of number N into addends 1,2,3,4, maximizing number of similar or close addends, preferring solution with maximum single coefficient (dor example, c) or neighbor ones (b,c)
*(one of the variants of coin change problem)*

```
a * 1 + b * 2 + c * 3 + d * 4  = N
```

You can build solution of this equation with dynamic programming, filling array [0..N] with lists of possible variants, and select the best variant.

Probably pre-selection might be used during DP building (don't include variants like a + d), but I am not sure that this approach always find good solution.